# SKLearn Pairwise Distances of a Vector Array

Tags: scikit-learn

I have a matrix X of shape  "X[n_samples, n_features]" .

I want to calculate pairwise distances between each samples. A possible result could be
Result[n_samples,n_samples] ; where Result[0][1] means the distance between the 0th vector and 1st vector.

How can I achieve this using "sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances" function?

As per the documentation [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html)! when X vector has the above shape, an additional array "Y" is expected. What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

The documentations explicitly say " and **optional** Y". So if you want to compute distances between two arrays, `Y` if the second array. If you don't, just don't pass a `Y`.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the following description about Y : "A second feature array only if X has shape [n_samples_a, n_features]."  . So can I conclude that Y is optional even when X has shape [n_samples_a, n_features]..?

Comment: X always has shape ``[n_samples_a, n_features]``, right? But I agree, the docstring is a bit odd.

Comment: What it tries to say that if ``metric="precomputed"`` Y is not valid.